# Google Analytics - 2 domains, on the same page (the same code)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have a domains: something.com and something.org
I created 2 property in GA, for each of that domains.

My problem is that I can't find good way to put it on the page.

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-2', 'auto', 'secondTracker');
    ga('secondTracker.send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Something is very wrong with this question. So your client wants one property per domain. Fine, but why do you think you need to do it with two trackers? This tracks traffic from domain A into domain B's analytics, and vice versa. Is that what you want? Why not just place the respective tracking codes onto the respective site? Sorry, please give the full story here.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch with `window.location.hostname`

```
<script>
switch(window.location.hostname) {
      case "domain1.com":
            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
            break;
      case "domain2.com":
            ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-2', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
            break;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `js` you can do that:

```
if(window.location.hostname == "something.org") {
    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-2', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
} else {
    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-2', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create second tracker:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto', 'secondTracker');
```

and then send events using it:

```
ga('secondTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

[GA documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/creating-trackers)

However why would You use two different properties? Use one and use filters to display reports. More info [here](https://moz.com/ugc/single-google-analytics-tracking-code-for-multiple-sites-when-to-use-how-to-report)

Comment: I update my question with your suggestion. Client wants to have one property for one domain.